# HTML table columns only playing sound of first audio for all

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a table with 2 columns per row whose columns on mouseover will play a corresponding sound. The issue is it's only playing the first sound test1.ogg for all columns?

```
window.onload = function() {
   var mySound = document.getElementById('mySound');
   var myIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('myIcon');

   for(var i = 0; i < myIcons.length; i++) {
      myIcons[i].onmouseover = function() {
        mySound.play();
        return false;
      };
   };
}; 

<tr>
   <td class="myIcon">Test1
      <audio id='mySound'  preload="auto"><source src='test1.ogg'/>
      </audio>
   </td>
   <td class="myIcon">Test2
      <audio id='mySound'  preload="auto"><source src='test2.ogg'/>
      </audio>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Id's have to be unique. But imagine you'll have 5000 cells in your table - then you'll end up with 5000 listeners hanging around. Not a good idea. Instead you can use just one listener on your parent element and get rid of all your classes and id-s to make the markup cleaner, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "TD") {
      e.target.childNodes[1].play();
      return false;
    }
  }, false);
};

<table id="myTable">
<tr>
   <td>Test1
      <audio preload="auto"><source src='test1.ogg'/></audio>
   </td>
   <td>Test2
      <audio preload="auto"><source src='test2.ogg'/></audio>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null with the above code.